# Gravity/Physics not working in Unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following Brackey's tutorial on how to create a simple 3D game in Unity (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4I0I3QJAvc&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5QFsefuO2RlAgWEz6EvVi6&index=8&ab_channel=Brackeys) however I can't seem to get the physics/gravity (rigid body?) to work properly. It was previously working on my main character (the cube) until I added in more grey cubes to be obstacles in a level. All gravity stopped and everything now begins to float into the air when the play button is pressed.

[image: objects floating away]

[image: player is selected so you can see rigid body settings]

^Player is selected so you can see rigid body settings.

New Behaviour 2 script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviour2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update


    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

FollowPlayer script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Player Collision script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NewBehaviour2 movement;
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Please let me know if you need any more photos. Thank you.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is of course in `c#`. Also just because you use a certain IDE (`visual-studio`) doesn't mean this question is about that IDE in specific.

Comment: I would check the collider size on the floor object .. it is probably just bigger than the visuals ...

Comment: Also why is there a Rigidbody on the `Camera` itself?

Answer (score 0):

You should use TriggerCollider for the grey boxes (just check the trigger option on the collider component), as they don't need gravity and they only trigger an action (Game Over I suppose). Then the script of the grey box should be changed to:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NewBehaviour2 movement;
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
        }
        
    }

}
```